# Someone could help me I have problems with the environment

Tags: python, django

```
(entorno) PS C:\\Users\\maner\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Secoed\\secoed-develop\> python manage.py createsuperuser Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "manage.py", line 22, in \<module\> main() 
File "manage.py", line 18, in main execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
File "C:\\Users\\maner\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Secoed\\entorno\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\__init_\_.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() 
File "C:\\Users\\maner\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Secoed\\entorno\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\__init_\_.py", line 416, in execute django.setup() 
File "C:\\Users\\maner\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Secoed\\entorno\\lib\\site-packages\\django\__init_\_.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 
File "C:\\Users\\maner\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Secoed\\entorno\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\registry.py", line 91, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry) 
File "C:\\Users\\maner\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Secoed\\entorno\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\config.py", line 193, in create import_module(entry) 
File "C:\\Users\\maner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\importlib\__init_\_.py", line 127, in import_module return \_bootstrap.\_gcd_import(name\[level:\], package, level) 
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1014, in \_gcd_import 
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 991, in \_find_and_load 
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 973, in \_find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'channels'
    
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title

Comment: do you use `django`? You could add tag `django`. Did you check your error in Google - I found similar question (and I close this question as duplicated)